# Reaching quota too soon on Youtube Data API V3 - optimizing search.list

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the `search.list` API to display a single result on my site. 
This is the call:

```
const request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
  q: query,
  part: 'id',
  type: 'video',
  maxResults: '1'
});
```

After a few calls, I see around 1K queries in my **Quotas** dashboard:

[image]

But on the **Metrics** dashboard I see only 20 requests (which is correct). This means every request takes 50-100 units. How can I optimize this request to take less units? since I only need one result.

[Edit] Resolved. Check out the comment by @MauricioAriasOlave for the right query optimization.

Comment: @Andreas thanks, but it says there `A simple read operation that only retrieves the ID of each returned resource has a cost of approximately 1 unit` so I'm still not sure about this behaviour. I guess my question boils down to how to optimize the `search.list` query so it takes less units (currently ~50). I only need the first result.

Comment: Then maybe it's because you have multiple queries in the `q` parameter?

Comment: @Andreas it's a simple string: `const query = 'adele'`

Comment: Also, I found this `Quota impact: A call to this method has a quota cost of 100 units.`, which is double of your current estimation

Comment: @Andreas still, not sure why it's so much for getting a single result

Comment: @DalmTo I edited the question. Please remove the duplicate, since it doesn't answer the need to optimize the query.

Comment: @shaym2 can you use the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=surfing) for create a try-it version of your request? I think I have a way to optimize your query, but I preffer added as an answer.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave sure, here it is:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id&maxResults=1&q=surfing&type=video&_h=3&

Comment: @shaym2 since it seems I wont be able to post an answer my suggestion as follows: If you only need get the `videoId` of your search results, you can use this sample [I made using the Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=surfing&fields=items%252Fid%252FvideoId&_h=2&). If you want more details in the search results, I advice you [edit] your question and add the specific details you want retrieve.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Amazing, thank you. following your advice and adding **fields** to my query (which only differs from yours by requesting `id` instead of `snippet` in the **part**) reduced the query to 20 units. This is the chosen answer.

Comment: @shaym2 you welcome. I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: It seems that Mauricio's suggestion does not work anymore. Can anyone check? I'm testing it here and facing the 100 units being consumed, always :(