# Youtube stats of all videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&key=<mykey>&forUsername=<mychannalname>`

I am trying to find all the videos stats of my channel but its not working. Why?

Comment: Because the purpose of [`forUsername`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername) is not to give you stats info about your channel's videos, but to provide the meta data info about that channel itself.

Comment: @stva how can we get complete stats?

Comment: Use [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) in tandem with [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list). The former endpoint for to get the list of IDs of your uploaded videos and the latter endpoint for the get the stats info. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64720048/8327971) is the procedure (exemplified using Python).

Comment: Playlists: list returning empty list, i am sending only id<mykey> in request

Comment: @VishakhaSehgal [edit] your question and add the URL of the requerst you're sending and the current results.